# RecyclerView in FrameLayout overlapping other elements

Tags: android

In my android app, I am having following framelayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.AppointmentFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.jhonnyx2012.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datePicker" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My HorizontalPicker is rendered correctly, however, recycler_view (RecycleView) content is being overlapped in HorizontalPicker.

I have tried various suggestions offered in Stakeoverflow, however nothing works.
Can somebody help me reolving the issue. I have also tried setting the android:layout_height="0dp" as suggested in other such issue, however it stops displaying the content of Recyclerview.

Comment: It will help if you share screenshots of your layout in design as well as runtime. Your RelativeLayout inside the FrameLayout is unnecessary. Just use ConstraintLayout instead of both FrameLayout and RelativeLayout to reduce complexity and code size. Also, your RelativeLayout is set to android:layout_height="wrap_content" and the same is with your RecyclerView. If the RecyclerView does not have any item in it then it will collapse. Make sure you're adding an item in RecyclerView and run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with the following. It may work.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datePicker" />
```